# how to retum multiple records with datatables if we have more than one record returned on the second foreach loop

Tags: c#

I have two nested foreach statement Aspect Id and Aspect returns only single record as final result.I have 11 activities  which some of the aspects associated come with 3 items paired as AspecId and Aspect   but after the loop I get only one  displayed on my report Aspect what am I missing.

```
 foreach (RiskActivity found in activities)
 {
    List<RiskAspect> aspects = RiskProvider.ListRiskAspect(found.Id).ToList();

    DataRow impactRow = impactTable.NewRow();

    impactRow.SetField("ActivityId", found.Id);
    impactRow.SetField("Activity", found.Activity);
    impactRow.SetField("OrderNumber", found.OrderNumber);   

    foreach (RiskAspect riskAspect in aspects)
    {           
        impactRow.SetField("AspectId", riskAspect.Id);
        impactRow.SetField("Aspect", riskAspect.AspectHazard);     
    }
```

Comment: You are setting the same field over and over again in your second for loop?

Comment: How do I make sure that I return a list of Aspects returned from a second foreach loop and set the fields as I was setting them?

Comment: I think what you want is probably `impactRow["AspectId"] = impactRow["AspectID"].ToString() + "," +riskAspect.Id` or something along the lines of that

Comment: I tried that to no avail

Comment: You are only creating (and then keep updating) 1 single `DataRow` instance, thus you end up with only 1 row. You need to create 1 `DataRow` for each row you want to add to the `impactTable`.

Comment: Thanks I understand but I am not too familiar with Datatables can you give me an example where another row is created on the same impactTable?

Comment: I have tried to  add a new Datarow with a different object name  in the second foreach but I get an exception

Answer (score 0):

The second loop should just create the aggregated AspectId and Aspect. Then you update them to the column:

```
var ids = new StringBuilder();
var aspects = new StringBuilder();
foreach (RiskAspect riskAspect in aspects)
{           
    ids.AppendLine(riskAspect.Id);  // You can use Append to keep in the same line
    aspects.AppendLine(riskAspect.AspectHazard);
}
impactRow.SetField("AspectId", ids.ToString());
impactRow.SetField("Aspect", aspects.ToString());
```

Comment: Perfect this worked like charm thanks a million Pedreiro